# Как обратиться к событию через TControl?

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Есть переменная `Pr_Component`, в которую попадают компоненты («*Edit*» и «*Button*»)

```
Var
  Pr_Component: TControl;

  …
  Pr_Component := FindDragTarget(L_PosCursor, false);
```

Таким образом в `Pr_Component` я получил компонент, например `Button1`.

Как мне достучаться к его событию `OnMouseMove`? У него есть свойство `OnDragOver`, но мне не удалось к нему достучаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что есть "достучаться"?

```
if Pr_Component is TButton then
begin
  TButton(Pr_Component).OnDragOver ...
  TButton(Pr_Component).OnMouseMove ...
end;
```

Comment: замечу, что события эти должны быть где-нибудь на уровне  `TControl/TWinControl`, поэтому приводить чисто к `TButton` смысла нет, особенно при условии, что может приходит и `TEdit`.